# Using MERGE into a view with an INSTEAD OF trigger and OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-merge

I'm trying to use MERGE on a view that has an INSTEAD OF trigger and also output the identity value that was inserted, but I get the error "The column reference "inserted.Whatever" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement. It seems to error any time I use inserted in the OUTPUT clause.

A highly simplified example:

```
/* Cleanup
DROP VIEW Test_1;
DROP TABLE Test1;
*/
GO
CREATE TABLE Test1
(
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50),
    LastName    NVARCHAR(50),
    ID          INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
);
GO
CREATE VIEW Test_1
AS
SELECT FirstName, LastName, ID
FROM Test1;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER tiu_Test_1 ON Test_1
  INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS

MERGE INTO Test1 T
USING(SELECT * FROM inserted) S
ON T.ID = S.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET FirstName = S.FirstName,
        LastName = S.LastName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES(S.FirstName, S.LastName);
GO
-- Test MERGE
DECLARE @test   TABLE
(
    ID  INT
);
MERGE INTO Test_1 T
USING(VALUES(N'Jules', N'Vern'))
AS S(FirstName, LastName)
ON T.FirstName = S.FirstName
  AND T.LastName = S.LastName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES(S.FirstName, S.LastName)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @test;
```

I know this example doesn't actually need the INSTEAD OF trigger. Without the trigger, it works fine, but my actual use case is selecting from and updating multiple tables.

The reason I'm using MERGE instead of the normal INSERT/UPDATE is that I want to match the identity value with a key that's not being inserted. MERGE lets me do this, but INSERT does not.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe use the old-fashioned method instead of MERGE. It doesn't buy you what you probably think it buys you anyway ([read this post in full](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)).

Comment: The main reason I'm using MERGE (not shown in the example) is I'm trying to match a key from the data I'm inserting to the identity being inserted without actually inserting that key into the view.

Comment: It also appears that UPDATE with OUTPUT doesn't work either, e.g.
    UPDATE Test_1
    SET FirstName = 'James'
    OUTPUT inserted.ID;